# How I Get return Variable if get function javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, blob

how i get return javascript blob data ?
i have the code like this .
i want upload file via blob to ajax callback

```
function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            //console.log(reader.result);
            var data = reader.result;
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            //console.log('Error: ', error);
        };

        return reader.result;
    }
```

Comment: `FileReader` `load` event is asynchronous

Comment: `var data = reader.result` is precisely when you get your result. Not on the last line, which is executed earlier (too early).

Comment: Note while the possible duplicate uses jQuery the issue is the same. You can only process the response within your `onload` I suppose you could use promises or pass a callback: `getBase64(file, onLoadCallback)`  then do `onLoadCallback(reader.result)` inside `onload`

Comment: @Nope can you give me example code dude ?